# What are names for territories in space?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

So in my universe the galaxy is divided up into cubical volumes of space of 50, 500, 5000, and 50000 light years (roughly it's actually divided into my own unit types, but they're roughly equal). There are 1000 of the previous areas in the next area up.

Currently I'm calling them Sectors, Blocks, Grids, and Octants, but that doesn't really work, nor does "Quadrant" for the last one, especially since a sector really applies to any area of space in reality so the 50000ly area can be called a sector as much as the 50ly area.

So what are some other names for areas like this?

I'm talking about titles like sector, zone, territory, region, etc. None of those fit and I'm sure I am missing more and limiting my scope of thinking largely due to star trek.

Comment: What about [quadtree region/cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) ?

Comment: This might be a good question over at scifi.stackexchange.com where they may have more fluency with such matters.

Comment: @Graffito I don't think that would work, being as problematic as Quadrant and Octant.

Comment: @Mitch I doubt it, and even if it was, that would limit the range of words that they'd answer with, mostly to a range of words that I probably wouldn't use so it would be largely futile.

Comment: You could call them *blocks, neighborhoods, sections, super-sections*

Comment: @Jim I dunno why but your comment triggered me to think that maybe the best course is to go with Sector - KiloSector - MegaSector - GigaSector - etc which makes it very expandable... and now I'm wondering how big the biggest SI unit would be.. >.> Looked into it and it was too tantalizing so extending SI units 2 Magnitudes with Nove- and Deka- and now a DekaSector which is the outragous 500billion lightyears ^.^ I think this works.

Comment: Not as expandable as @Durakken excellent suggestion, but with a lower mathematic connotation: cube, supercube, hypercube, ultracube.

Comment: This isn't a question about English per se.  There are many terms such as "sector" and "quadrant" that could be used, but, given that this is not discussed outside of the sci-fi community, there is no established usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Sci-Fi SE site or somewhere similar to that.

Comment: Should be in Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: @Spencer go tell them that.

Comment: I started with a meta post; maybe someome with actual influence can do just that. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/should-elu-clarify-with-other-se-sites-what-constitutes-a-suitable-single-word

Answer (score 1):

All the obvious regional words I thought of were from Star Trek as well. Have you considered using a foreign language word to stand in for the territory/sub-district descriptor? Oblast, Gobol, Baladiyah, Opshtina, Canton, etc?

A few others: field, range, realm, domain, district, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_division

Comment: The problem with that link is that they are talking about political areas, where as I'm looking for non-politcal terms. --- As far as other languages... I pointed this out in worldbuilding which this actually belongs in but they refused it was told to ask here... so I'm looking for foreign language words too, I just don't know what they'd be.

Comment: Hexahedron? So much cooler than a block.

Comment: Hexahedron is a shape meaning 16 sided... where are the other 10 sides coming from?

Comment: That would be a hexadecagon.

Comment: I see... my mistake I was relating it to hexadecimal. I dunno. It doesn't sound like something people would use. Like they say cube rather than hexahedron ^.^